# jquery-migrate: filter out warnings from specific files?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-migrate

I trying to migrate from jQuery 2.2.4 to jQuery 3.4.1, and to that end I'm using `jquery-migrate-3.1.0.js`.

My problem is that it generates warnings for a library I use (Telerik Kendo UI), over which I have no control. Since all those warnings come from the same file `kendo.all.js`, I was wondering if there's a way to filter out all warnings coming from this file, so that I can concentrate on fixing issues in my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo is a bundle of components for jQuery and usually comes with jQuery version inside that bundle. I would suggest you to use newer kendo version and to include jQuery from kendo js folder. You can see supported version of jQuery per Kendo version: [Supported versions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/jquery-support)

I can presume you are using Kendo UI 2016.3.914 (R3 2016) version or later, that is compatible with jQuery 2.2.x, for jQuery 3.4.1 you need at least Kendo UI 2019.2.514 (R2 2019) version or higher.

I know its not an answer you are looking for but i strongly suggest don't try to use newer jQuery version with old kendo, it will end in disaster.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question: I'm trying to use jQuery 3.4.1, which is compatible with all recent versions of Kendo UI. All the warnings generated by jquery-migrate exist because they want to remain compatible with really old versions of jQuery, but they're preventing me from seeing where I need to update my code.